# Sum values from a SQL table to a value from other SQL table

Tags: php, sql

I have a PHP page like this:

| ID | Name | Hours Flown |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joao | 7 |
| 2 | Andre | 10 |
| 3 | Tiago | 15 |

And I want that "Hours Flown" column show a value from one column from a SQL table (users) with a sum of another SQL table (flights) where ID matches the "users" table.

I have a `while($row = $result_list_pilots->fetch_assoc())` to show the table if that helps...

SQL query for now is a bit simple "`SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY name;`". Already tried some `JOIN` examples but without success as the `imported_hours` gets duplicated as result from flights table is being found.

Tables:
[Tables][image: 1]

How to do this?

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question to add the query you're using to output this data. Also please add the relevant tables and columns in those tables. Searching for `mysql SUM` and `mysql JOIN` will help. You are likely looking for something like `SELECT u.id, u.name, SUM(f.hours) FROM users u JOIN flights f ON f.id = u.id GROUP BY u.id`, but without more info this is just a guess.

Comment: Do you have some SQL to give us a starting point?

Comment: Sorry about that and thanks for your attention. Edited as suggested!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here is what you want :

```
SELECT 
u.ID
, u.Name
, SUM(ISNULL(f.HoursFlown,0)) + MAX(Imported_hours) 'Hours Flown'
FROM Users u 
LEFT JOIN Flights f 
ON u.ID = f.User_id -- or whatever the fk is 
GROUP BY u.ID, u.Name
```

Comment: It works very well, but users that don't have records on "flights" table are not shown. Can we make it so those are visible too, showing only "Imported_hours"?

Comment: yes by changing the inner join to outer join

Comment: With outer join i get a syntax error. Instead I replaced `SUM(f.HoursFlown) + MAX(Imported_hours)` by `ifnull(SUM(f.HoursFlown),"0") + MAX(u.Imported_hours)`, and it worked as expected. Much thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.ID, u.Name, SUM(f.HoursFlown)
FROM Users u 
INNER JOIN Flights f ON u.Name = f.Name
GROUP BY u.ID, u.Name
```